Custom magic file database entry with negative offset
I'm currently trying to write a custom file magic entry to recognize some company specific file format.
This format, however, has it's magic bytes at the end of the file, instead of the beginning. The length of the file is also different from file to file.
In the man magic on my Ubuntu system with file version 5.41 I found the following:

offset   A number specifying the offset (in bytes) into the file of the data which is to be tested.  This offset can be a negative number if it is:
The first direct offset of the magic entry (at continuation level 0), in which case it is interpreted an offset from end end of the file going backwards.

Following this explanation, I have attempted to write a magic file in the following format:
-0  byte    0xA2    company format
!:mime application/custom

However, I don't get any matches using this magic on a file with the last byte being 0xA2 (with file -m <file> <company file>). Instead of my custom rule, the company file still matches data.
When trying to check the printout with file -m <magic> -c, it seems a bit broken as well (it's missing the -):
unknown, 0: Warning: using regular magic file `<magic>'
cont    offset  type    opcode  mask    value   desc
1: > 0 byte&,=-94,"company format"]

When checking the matches using file -m <magic> -k -l <company file> however, I get the following output, which leads me to believe that something should be working.
Set 0:
Binary patterns:
Strength =  40@1: company format  [application/custom]
Text patterns:
Set 1:
Binary patterns:
Text patterns:

Could anyone point me in the right direction for this?

I don't consider -0 as a negative number. I suggest to try -1 instead of -0.

You are right, this solves the issue! Thanks a lot!
Interestingly, in the magic docs -0 is used in as well, when explaining the offset operation, (without it being a second level check): -0      offset  x       this file is %lld bytes
weird! Which is why I got so hung up on -0 and didn't consider that it isn't a valid number...

From these observations I imagine the following concept: The end is after the last byte. Then -0 would be the position of the end after the last byte, and the corresponding offset represents the file size. And -1 is one byte before the end, i.e. just before the last byte you want to check.

The comment by bodo solved the issue for me: Instead of using -0 which isn't a valid (int) number, I used -1.
With this change, my custom magic file reads:
-1  byte    0xA2    company format
!:mime application/custom

and works as expected.
